# How Roles.AddUserToRole works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am using following code to add roles to user:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, userRole);
```

Now in next line, I am checking if user is in role:

```
bool isUserInRole = Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, userRole);
```

Above line return `false` until I restart IIS Express. I am trying to assign roles to a user on the fly.

Why `AddUserToRole` not working in runtime? Did I missed something?

Comment: Where are you running the code?

Comment: In Visual Studio on my local windows machine

Comment: Sorry, I mean where within your project.  Within a controller action?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in controller action.